# Тормзит сайт при переносе на VPS PHP7

Tags: apache, сервер, php7, vps

Раньше был хостинг -

```
56 * Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz
ОЗУ свободно:132680 / 515776 Мб.
Нагрузка:5.27 load average
```

Все работало ок, быстро и тд

Сейчас перенес на VPS -

```
Процессор   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5675 @ 3.07GHz
Оперативная память  286 / 1024 MiB
Размер дискового пространства   23.91 GiB
Файл подкачки (swap)    1024 MiB
```

Сайт тормозит до 4 секунд загрузка...

И там и там PHP7

pumud.ru через раз страница грузит за 0.5с, а так 5c

Comment: А вы не могли привести данные по таймингам? тормозит сеть, страница генерируется 3 минуты или у пользователя рисуется 2 минуты? хоть какие-то данные.

Comment: @Axenow сайт - pumud.ru через раз страница грузит за 0.5с, а так 5

Comment: Отлично, что это нам дало. То, что у вас много картинок и грузятся они долго. Что у вас за сервер крутится - не написано, но буду верить, что nginx. Поставьте несколько таймеров в код php от начала генерации страницы и до конца. Обновите страницу раз 20 и посмотрите на результаты. Если они будут все примерно одинаковые - идите к владельцу VPS и выясняйте, почему сеть проседает.

Как-то так. )

Comment: Т.е понизили сервер до 1Гб памяти ( _286 / 1024 MiB_ )? Так он свопится небось при таких ресурсах

Comment: То есть вы убавили процесорную мощность, грубо говоря, в 56 раз, а память — в 500, и и до того нехило нагруженный сервер у вас стал тормозить? Действительно, непонятно...

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev не путайте выделенный сервер с shared-хостингом

Comment: Данных слишком мало, тормозить может абсолютно что угодно: HDD/SSD, процессор, своп, запросы к базе, сеть, нехватка процессов апача, соседи по серверу. Мониторьте, читайте логи, поставьте какой-нибудь Munin и анализируйте графики

Comment: @andreymal вот именно. Раньше летал на шареде, а теперь под весь VPS выделен 1 гиг, больше половины которого съела система, свободных 256М. Где тут апачу рекорды показывать? А если на этом же VPS еще и БД, то там непрерывный своп идет

Comment: @DmitryKozlov одного гига с лихвой хватает для небольших сайтов, если руки не из странных мест растут и апач нормально настроен

Comment: На самом деле да, дело в VPS... Написал им. Вообще то 1гб реально хватит и хостинг с VPS вообще разные вещи